# Send post request from visitors network? Possible?

Tags: json, post

I have an post request php code i use to get streaming urls so i can broadcast them to my visitors.
Apparently other subscription service i use has stronger security and it requests that stream url be accessed only from the ip you firstly sent request from to get that streaming url.

So i need when user opens channel1.php that actually post request is sent from his ip address (instead of my servers) so he can watch stream.
Possible?

Here is the code

```
<?php

$params = array ('password' => 'mypassword', 'username' => 'mysecretusername');

$query = http_build_query ($params);

$contextData = array ( 
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                        "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n"."User-Agent: okhttp/2.5.0",
            'content'=> $query );

$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));

$result =  file_get_contents (
              'http://api.source.stream/streams/1/sign',  // page url
              false,
              $context);

$json = json_decode($result, true);
$pink = $json[url];
echo $json[url];
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you would like to try something like this

```
<script>
// Sending and receiving data in JSON format using POST mothod
//
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://your.url.com/streams/1/sign";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(json.username + ", " + json.password)
    }
}
var data = JSON.stringify({"username":"YOURUSERHERE","password":"YOURURLHERE"});
xhr.send(data);
</script>
```

But I really do not know how to print out answer in php from their server after you post it.
I just know how to send it.